# Records with comma seperator are not exported correctly in mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, export

i am using the below command to export a contacts collection's fields f1 and f2 to contacts.csv

```
mongoexport --db users --collection contacts --csv  --out /opt/backups/contacts.csv --fields f1,f2
```

its working fine and data is exported to csv.

the problem is only with f2 field's records export.

f2 field is stored in db with comma seperated values as 1,samuel,it.

I think mongo is exporting in to csv , considering  comma as a seperator.

so, 1 , samuel and it ane exported into 3 different cells in csv file as below,

```
field1  field2
====   ====         ======     ==
1         1                 samuel    it

instead i want it as follows

field1  field2
====   ====        
1         1,samuel,it
```

BTW I am currently using mongo 1.6.5

Comment: If I were you, I would consider upgrading my mongo to 2.4 first, and see if this issue still exists.

Comment: What application or tool are you using to import the CSV?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB 1.6.5 was released in December, 2010 and a *lot* has changed since then. It would definitely be worth upgrading to at least MongoDB 2.2 if not 2.4.

If a full upgrade of MongoDB is not an option, you could try running `mongoexport` from MongoDB 2.4 against your current database. The command line tools should generally be backward compatible.

It looks like the `mongoexport` CSV formatting was made more compliant with the release of MongoDB 2.0 and changes for [SERVER-1097](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1097) ("mongoimport / export should adhere to CSV spec"), but there could certainly be subsequent improvements or fixes.

I just tried a simple test with MongoDB 1.6.5 and the `mongoexport --csv` format seemed OK:

```
field1,field2
1,"1,samuel,it"
```

Another possibility is that the issue lies in the application/tool that you are trying to use to import the CSV.  There are several different interpretations for what a "valid" [CSV formatted file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) should look like.  Everyone agrees a CSV contains fields separated by commas, but field escaping can vary.